# how to execute a multiple data-ng-app in sequence in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two `ng-app` in my application `app1` and `app2` and two controllers `firstcontroller` and `secondcontroller` respectively.

The problem is it first executes 2nd controller then first controller.

But i want to execute in sequence, like 1st controller execution then 2nd controller.

please provide solution for that.
thanks in advance.

```js
var app1 = angular.module('firstapp', []);
app1.controller("firstcontroller",function($scope){
    $scope.arr1={name:'arjun'};
    alert($scope.arr1.name);
}); 
var app2 = angular.module('secondapp', []);
app2.controller("secondcontroller",function($scope){
    console.log("come to second app");
    $scope.arr2={title:'kumar'};
    alert($scope.arr2.title);
});
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"),['secondapp']);
```

```html
<body >
    <div id="app1" data-ng-app="firstapp" data-ng-controller="firstcontroller">
        <p>{{arr1.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="app2" data-ng-app="secondapp" data-ng-controller="secondcontroller">
        <p>{{arr2.title}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) said

> To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually
>   bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap

While it is possible to have multiple ng-app on the page but only one ng-app directive will be automatically instantiated and initialized by the Angular framework.

Now order can be mantianed by using

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
 angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"),['secondapp']);
});
```

Here is plunker for you [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QxmaoEghbX6gYXx00dAl?p=preview)

Comment: I am not getting exactly what do you want to say ? because i am not using (document).ready(function(){....}); so where i have to place the code...

Comment: In the initial step i was explaining that it is not recommended to use multiple ng-app in the single page but you can use it with manual bootstrapping. And in the last step i was telling you how to use it.
It may be possible that you placed angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"),['secondapp']); directly in your script which will run automatically  as the script file loaded even before your 'firstapp'.So, You must place this code inside angular.element(document).ready(function() {.}. So that it will run after the document is prepared and automatic boostrapping (of  firstapp) is done.